# how to fill char array filled with uint8_t

Tags: c++, char, uint8t

I want to create an char array and give 8 bit values. For example; `buf[0] = 0000 0001; // 1` and `buf[1] = 0000 0010; //2` and so on.

What I see buf is *empty* when I watch it with breakpoints. In other posts people giving advice like "put (unsigned) cast if you want to see integers", it works just for cout.

**All I want is to fill a char array with ordered increasing numbers.** I used int but it is 4 bytes, instead I thought giving uint8_t is better for filling char array with numbers.

```
char *buf = new char[5];

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = i;
    }
```

[EDIT]
Here is what I see, I changed loop int this way [image]

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Comment: Why are you using uint8_t instead of just char?

Comment: How did you determine that the array is empty at the end?

Comment: Code looks good except that the values would start at zero, not one, as you indicate in the prose.

Comment: @Quentin visual studio 2019

Comment: @MadPhysicist because I coudn't see a way to fill a char array with inetegers

Comment: @Deniz. You do realize that int8_t is char and uint8_t is unsigned char, right? Don't let the name char confuse you. It's still an integer type.

Comment: @MadPhysicist even though I use int8_t, the array is still empty

Comment: The first element will be zero. Are you giving up too early?

Comment: Also, please show an example with a printout of the array before and after. We can't see your debugger, and I can't reproduce your issue given the information shown.

Comment: That being said, I'm printing array values with %02X in a loop, not %s

Comment: @MadPhysicist the output is literally zero, an empty array, when I make it fixed size char array it is fixed. I guess there is something with the pointer type. As solution suggested I will try vector for the pointer char array

Comment: @Deniz. Please show how you know it's empty. Like I said, I'm seeing something different, so until I know what you're looking at, we're talking about different things.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I put a screenshot of what I see

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your debugger is assuming that all `char*` point at C-style strings. Since the first `char` it encounters has the value zero, it marks the end of said string.

Most debuggers allow you to provide arbitrary expressions to evaluate. It will probably display the array correctly if you provide the information that it *is* actually an array, using a cast:

```
reinterpret_cast<char(*)[5]>(buf)
```

In any case, you should not use `new` but rather `std::vector<char>`, which additionally the debugger should know how to display correctly.

Comment: I can not use vectors, I send UDP packages, and sendto method of library <WS2tcpip.h> only accepts char * arrays

Comment: @Deniz `std::vector` has a `data()` function for exactly this purpose :)